# Many to Many child removel JPA

Tags: many-to-many

Hi i have many to many relationship and entities are here:

```
  @Entity
  public class Company implements Serializable 
  {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer idcompany;
//bi-directional many-to-many association to Client
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name="company_client",
  joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="company_idcompany", 
  referencedColumnName="idcompany"),
  inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="client_idclient", 
  referencedColumnName="idclient"))
  Set<Client> clients = new HashSet<Client>();
```

and second entity

```
@Entity
public class Client implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int idclient;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="clients",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST , fetch = 
FetchType.LAZY )
Set<Company> companies = new HashSet<Company>();
```

and here is details of  date in all 3 tables

```
 ---------------------------------------------
  company table         client table       company_client  table 
   id   name            id      name         fk_compny    fk_client
    1    Oracle         1        Abc          1              1
                        2        XYZ          1              2
```

when i want to remove row from client table e.g "XYZ" id=2

```
      Client cl = em.find(Client.class,2);
     em.remove(cl);
```

it throws exception "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails "  .
How to remove this row

Comment: Why `CascadeType.PERSIST`? This looks like the deletion is not cascaded, so the client would still be in the join table, but the relation would become invalid once the client is removed.

Comment: your code implies that when you do CRUD operation it will only allow create i.e. persist you have mentioned `@ManyToMany(mappedBy="clients",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST , fetch = FetchType.LAZY )` change it to `@ManyToMany(mappedBy="clients",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY )` it should work.

Comment: I have done that but in vain(no success  )